# xml standard symbol notation, "-" meaning

Tags: xml, definition

I try understand XML definition, but stuck on 'CharData' token. It's taken from http://www.w3.org/TR/xml/#NT-Char. From regural expression I know that "-" is used for range, but don't get it in this case. Can somebody please explain me what is meaning of this expressions?

```
[14]    CharData       ::=      [^<&]* - ([^<&]* ']]>' [^<&]*)
[15]    Comment    ::=      '<!--' ((Char - '-') | ('-' (Char - '-')))* '-->'
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's explained in the [Notation](http://www.w3.org/TR/xml/#sec-notation) section of the same doc:

> **A - B**
>
> matches any string that matches **A** but does not match **B**.

In the particular case of CharData, it is defined as a sequence of any characters except `<` and `&`. That sequence, however, shouldn't contain `]]>` string (CDATA section-close delimiter).